# Fubini's Theorem for Complete Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\mathscr M, \mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr N, \mu)$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $(X\times Y, \overline {\mathscr M\otimes \mathscr N}, \overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu})$ the completion of $(X\times Y, \mathscr M\otimes \mathscr N, \mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu).$

The proofs of Fubini's theorem I have seen either extend the proofs on $(X\times Y, \mathscr M\otimes \mathscr N, \mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu)\ $ (left as an exercise in Folland) or do it directly in several steps (Royden).

I'd like to submit a somewhat different approach, and my question is whether it is correct. I will assume Fubini on $(X\times Y, \mathscr M\otimes \mathscr N, \mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu).$

$1).$ Suppose $f$ is integrable with respect to $\overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu}.$ Without loss of generality,  $f\ge 0.$ Now choose a  $\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu$- measurable function $g$ such that $f=g \quad \overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu}$ a.e. Then $h=f-g$ is $\overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu}$-measurable and equal to $0$ a.e. $\overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu}.$ Thus, $\tag 1 \int hd(\overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu})=0.$

Let $S=\left \{ (x,y):h(x,y)\neq 0 \right \}$.

$2).$ Since $h=0\quad \overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu}$-a.e., and since $\overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu}$ is complete, there is an $S\subseteq E\in \mathscr M\otimes \mathscr N$ such that $\overline {\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu}(S)=\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu(E)=0.$

$3).$ We have now $\mathscr \mu\otimes \mathscr \nu(E)=\int \nu (E_x)d\mu=0$ so $\nu(E_x)=0$ a.e. $\mu$ so $h_x=0$ a.e. $\mu$ and as $\nu$ is complete, $\int h_xd\nu$ exists and is equal to $0,$ a.e $\mu $ and $\nu, $ so we may conclude that,

$\tag2 \phi(x)=\int h_xd\nu=0$

Similarly, $\tag3 \psi(y)=\int h_yd\mu=0$

$4).$ On comparing these last results with $1).$ and using the fact that $h=f-g,$ we are done.

Comment: Consider adding the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are $\sigma$-finite, unless you are particularly interested in the non-$\sigma$-finite case.

Comment: Yes, thanks, because I guess if $X$ and $Y$ are not $\sigma$-finite, then Fubini may fail, the classic example being the product of Lebesgue measure and counting measure on $I\times I.$ Integration over the diagonal $D$ provides the counterexample. I think also $\mu\times \nu$ should be regular, so that the $g$ in the claim exists.